# C# Application couldn't find dlls locally

Tags: c#, dll, path, environment-variables

I have a 32 bit application that uses a DLL built by someone else, lets call it xyz.dll. This DLL has dependencies on few other old DLLs. All dlls are saved in the same folder where my app is located. My app compiles fine but in run time, it throws an error "Could not load file or assembly "xyz.dll" or one of its dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application"

I have 2 workarounds that seems to solve this problem. In first one I moved the DLLs to a separated folder and created a batch file to run the app. The batch file first add the dlls' path to the environment, then call the app. Interestingly if I leave the dlls in the same folder with the app and just add this to the path, it wouldn't work.

The second way also moved dlls to a folder and add this path to user environment variable and run the exe directly. Either one of these solutions requires extra steps which is not ideal for app deployment. I am wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: "Is not a valid Win32 application" strongly suggests that your app is trying to load a wrong dll from a wrong folder. Take [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

When your dll is in the same folder as the application, it is that dll that the application attempts to load, and this fails, as you said.

When you move the dll to another folder and add the pathname of that folder to the PATH environment variable, the application works. In this case, the application is not attempting to load the dll that you have moved to another folder. If this were the case, it would fail. It must be loading another version of the dll that is in one of the folder paths that are in your PATH environment variable.

Simply use Windows search to find all copies of your dll file on your computer. You will be able to determine where that other dll is.